# why empty line is not getting stored in variable

Tags: bash, shell

I am using below code

```
    #! /bin/bash
for host in $(cat ./server.txt)
do 
    echo "$host"

done
```

server.txt contains :

```
     server1.com
     server2.com

     server3.com


     server4.com
```

But the above code is giving below output:

```
     server1.com
     server2.com
     server3.com
     server4.com
```

i.e its not taking account of empty lines.How can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while read host; do echo "$host"; done < server.txt
```

With the code you provided, the file as a single string is given as the 4th argument to the `for` command. The shell then splits the string *using arbitrary whitespace as a delimiter* (assuming you have not altered the `IFS` variable).

Comment: its not getting last line.i.e server4.com

Comment: You could also set `IFS` first: `IFS="\n"` but I agree it's probably better to use `read`.

Comment: @grails_enthu, is your file missing a newline on the last line?

Comment: @glenn got it.The last line also should be terminated by a new line.otherwise above script will ignore last line.* i saw your edit after my comment.thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

empty lines are not there because they are considered whitespaces used to separate word values.

use this:

awk '{print $1}' server.txt

```
 server1.com
 server2.com

 server3.com


 server4.com
```

Comment: you mean "whitespace used to separate *words*"

Comment: Printing is not the main concern here, I need to store values in variable.

Comment: glenn. thanks, you are right. i meant to say values, not vars. i have now edited it. grails, thanks for pointing out the difference. i did not realize that you want the variable in the shell environment only.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative

```
s=$(cat -E ./server.txt) 
while [ ${#s} != 0 ]
 do
  echo ${s%%\$*}
  s=${s#*\$}
 done
```